# How do I find an IP address of an AWS hosted web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

Given the URL `http://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xx?`. How would I find its IP address?

I have no access to the AWS console

I've tried nslookup and pinging, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `x-x-x-x` values just after the `ec2` portion of your URL are the public IP address of the EC2 server. Just copy that and replace the `-` characters with `.` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use domain lookups like the following - type dns like “cnews.com” etc.

http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php
https://www.whois.com/whois/